# PostgreSQL - "Include Error Detail" connection string parameter - how sensitive is the information returned?

Tags: postgresql, connection-string

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

> Include Error Detail -
> When enabled, PostgreSQL error and notice details are included on PostgresException.Detail and PostgresNotice.Detail. These can contain sensitive data.

If I provide the "Include Error Detail=True" in the connection stringg to PostgreSQL, what sensitive data do I need to be concerned about? If the query itself is returned in an exception or error message, that is fine by me, but if say the connection password were returned in plaintext obviously that would be bad. What sensitive data is conditionally included in errors based on this parameter?

Comment: For example if your query is using dblink, the error might include the password used for the dblink connection (not for the original connection).  Returning this to the user who sent you that query in the first place shouldn't be a problem, but returning it all the way to the end user who only sent pieces which were turned into the query might be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These messages include no sensitive data that the database user should not see. So I wouldn't worry, unless perhaps you show the information to the application user rather than logging them. Your database user may have access to information that the application user shouldn't see.

Comment: Ah, if it is information from the query itself (or about the schema) then I definitely am not concerned.

Comment: @Anssssss No, it can also contain *data* (from tables or parameters) not just schema info

Comment: @Dagrada there's nothing wrong with the answer. It states that the error details can contain any data that the database user could see. "Sensitive data" refers to data that is stored in the database but for which the database user has no access permission.

Comment: @Dagrada I said "information that the database user should not see", not "information the end user should not see".

Comment: Thank you - I assumed "is returned in an exception or error message" meant "to the user". This data is OK for the "database user" i.e. developer. Comment retracted.

Answer (score 3):

The error message will contain actual data from the database. For example:

```
DETAIL: Key (policy_provider_id, charge)=(194, 0) is duplicated.
```

This data could be sensitive so it is omitted from the output.

Answer (score 0):

When enabled, PostgreSQL error and notice details are included on xref:Npgsql.PostgresException.Detail?displayProperty=nameWithType and xref:Npgsql.PostgresNotice.Detail?displayProperty=nameWithType. **These can contain sensitive data.**

https://github.com/npgsql/doc/blob/main/conceptual/Npgsql/connection-string-parameters.md

Comment: I'm not sure what your answer is trying to add. I already know what the documentation says and it was in the original question.